# He kicked me out of the bed

Tags: grammar, prepositions

He was sleeping close to the side of the bed.

My son kicked me and I fell off the bed.

> "He kicked me out of the bed."
>
> "He kicked me off of the bed."

Do they have different mean? Which preposition should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I'd probably use "kicked me *off*". As @Tᴚoɯɐuo mentioned, The phrase "kick someone out of bed" is commonly used to mean "insist that someone leave the bed", and does not necessarily imply a physical kick, and this is true in general of the phrase "kick someone out of <somewhere>".

With that said, I think that most English speakers would have no problem figuring out what you meant based on context. Either phrase would be understood, but "kick me off" is probably the more correct phrase in your case.

Answer (score 3):

**To kick someone out** is often a figurative, not a literal, expression. It means to demand that someone exit a place or leave a group.

> They kicked him out of the glee club because he couldn't stay on tune.
>
> He was surfing the web and his wife kicked him out of bed because she wanted to sleep.

**To kick something|someone off**  when used literally, means to swing the foot with force, causing someone|something to fall from its position or their position.

> He kicked the flowerpot off the porch by accident.
>
> The martial arts contestant kicked his opponent off the mat.

But with {something} it can be used figuratively to mean "To inaugurate, to start something":

> The chemistry teacher kicked off the semester with an experiment that produced a small explosion and a big puff of smoke, impressing the students.